# How to order fields on index creation (SQL Server 2005 +)?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, indexing, performance

As [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc135978.aspx)'s figure 4 says, SQL Server 2005 + can return you a list of missing indexes. It stores 2 important info about missing indexes:

[EqualityUsage],[InequalityUsage]

If I have a missing index where:

[EqualityUsage]='col1',[InequalityUsage]='col2'

Should I create an index with Indexed Key Columns:

'col1,col2'

or

'col2,col1'

?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

col1, col2

[CREATE INDEX](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345434.aspx)

> To convert the information returned by
>   sys.dm_db_missing_index_details into a
>   CREATE INDEX statement, **equality
>   columns should be put before the
>   inequality columns**, and together they
>   should make the key of the index.
>   Included columns should be added to
>   the CREATE INDEX statement using the
>   INCLUDE clause.

Answer (score 0):

if you had only one of the two to search with, which would it be? list that first

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @Rostyslav Dzinko, I strongly disagree. it provides a method to determine how to solve this and all similar future questions.