# SQL Index on two columns

Tags: sql-server, indexing

Here's my simple scenario:

I've a Users table and a Locations table. **ONE User** can be related to **MANY Locations** so I've a UserLocation table which is as follows:

```
ID (int-Auto Increment) PK
UserID (Int FK to the Users table)
LocID (Int FK to the Locations table)
```

Now, as ID is the PK it is Indexed by default in SQL-Server. I was a bit confused about the other two columns:

> **OPT 1:** Shud I define an Index on both the columns like: 
>   IX_UserLocation_UserID_LocID
>
> OR
>
> **OPT 2:** Shud I define two separate Indexes like : IX_UserLocation_UserID
>   & IX_UserLocation_LocID

Pardon me if both do the same - in that case pls explain. If not - which one is better and why?

Comment: Do you really need the auto incrementing surrogate `id` field in the junction table? What is it there for? I'd make a composite Primary key on the 2 FK columns. What queries will be running against that table? Will they be looking up by `user`, `location` or both?

Comment: Thank you guys. Just FYI - the ID column is our tradition we keep it in all the tables, at most places it serves the purpose of unique record identifier. I know here UserID + LocID can be a composite PK but to simplify & standardize we keep the ID field. IF this is not convincing - forget the ID key for now!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should probably create two separate indexes. One thing that is often forgotten with foreign keys is the fact that deleting a user might cascade-delete the user-location relation in your table. If there is no index on userID, this might lead to a table-lock of your user-location relation. The same applies to deleting a location.

Comment: Does having 2 separate indexes cover any where clause combination of UserID and LocID. Is there any difference in performance?

Answer (score 3):

You need

- 2 columns

  - UserID (Int FK to the Users table)
  - LocID (Int FK to the Locations table)
- One PK on both `(UserID, LocID)`
- Another index on the reverse `(LocID, UserID)`

You may not need both indexes but it's rare

Edit, some links to other SO answers

- [SQL: Do you need an auto-incremental primary key for Many-Many tables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/790334/sql-do-you-need-an-auto-incremental-primary-key-for-many-many-tables/790359#790359)
- [SQL - many-to-many table primary key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2190272/sql-many-to-many-table-primary-key/2190283#2190283)
- [Difference between 2 indexes with columns defined in reverse order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1549847/difference-between-2-indexes-with-columns-defined-in-reverse-order/1550102#1550102)

Answer (score 2):

There are several things we hire the database for.  One is fast information retrieval and another is declarative referential integrity (DRI).

If you requirement is that a user may be related to a given location only once then you want a unique index on UserID & LocatonID.

If your question is how to retrieve the data fast the answer is -- it depends.  How are you accessing the data?  If you always get the entire set of locations for a user then I would probably use a clustered non-unique index on UserID.      If your access is "who is in locatin x?" then you probably want a clustered non-unique index on LocationID.

If you ask both questions you'll probably want both indexes (although you only get 1 clustered, so the 2nd index may want to use an INCLUDE to grab the other column).

Either way, you probalby don't want ID as your clustered index (the default when marking a column as PK in SSMS table designer).

HTH,
-eric

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the "***gbn***" answer. It will depend on the ***Where*** clause. Whether you are using user or location or both

Answer (score 0):

The best way to setup all the indexed you think you need on dev and check look at the [query plans](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178071.aspx) of the queries your app runs and see what indexes get read.